# Grey Background on clicking Drawer Items in React Native app

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

[image: On Long Press, getting grey background and it's overriding orange color]
[image: Clicking on Privacy Policy]

Problem: Grey Background when clicking/Long Press on items.

Requirement: How to change grey background to orange color when I press items?

```
<Drawer.Navigator
            drawerContent={(props)=><CustomDrawer {...props}/>}
            screenOptions={
                {
                    drawerStyle:{
                        width:300,
                        borderBottomEndRadius:15,

                    },
                    drawerLabelStyle:{
                        fontSize:18,
                        marginLeft:-10,
                        
                    },
                    drawerItemStyle:{
                        marginLeft:0,
                        marginRight:0,
                        paddingLeft:10
                        
                    },
                    drawerActiveBackgroundColor:'orange',
                    drawerActiveTintColor:'black',
                }
            }
        >
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'red',
          activeBackgroundColor: 'grey',
          inactiveTintColor: 'blue',
          inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
          labelStyle:{
            fontSize: 15,
            marginLeft:5
          }
        }}>
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

also follow the link
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9079

Comment: This code will not have any impact on the grey background color on Press.

Comment: Let me again reiterate my question. There are two items in the drawer menu, item which is selected by user is having orange background. If you will select privacy policy now, at the time when you press the item, it will highlight it in grey color, that what I want to change. If it possible to change the grey background width, let me know that also

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to try this.

```
<Drawer.Navigator 
screenOptions={{
drawerActiveBackgroundColor: ‘orange’
drawerActiveTintColor: ‘fff’
drawerInactiveTintColor: ‘#333’
}}
>
```

Comment: Let me again reiterate my question. There are two items in the drawer menu, item which is selected by user is having orange background. If you will select privacy policy now, at the time when you press the item, it will highlight it in grey color, that what I want to change. If it possible to change the grey background width, let me know that also